# switch statement on FormLoadEvent

Tags: c#, winforms, switch-statement

Please, what is wrong with this:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (Form2.Tag) //error
    {
        case "desc":
            MessageBox.Show("desc");
        break;

        case "sms":
            MessageBox.Show("sms");
        break;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property System.Windows.Forms.Control.Tag.get
```

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow is not in need of your SEO skills](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)".

Comment: OK, no more tags in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant to say `this.Tag`.  Referencing the `Tag` property will require an instance of `Form2`, hence the error message you received.

Edit:

Forgot `Tag` was an object.  Cast it to a string and your statement should work:

```
switch ((string)this.Tag)
```

Comment: I replaced Form2.Tag with this.Tag and got another error: A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type

Answer (score 2):

Since `Tag` is not a static property you won't be able to access it through class name i.e. Form2. Also Tag is of `object` type which you can't use in switch statement. Since your cases are of string type you may try the following:

```
 string tag = (string) this.Tag;
 switch (tag) //error
      {
           case "desc":
                MessageBox.Show("desc");
                break;
           case "sms":
                MessageBox.Show("sms");
               break;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:

```
switch ((string)this.Tag)
```